# Vim autocmd read .vim file

Tags: vim, autoload, autocmd

I put the `SyntaxAttr.vim` file in the `~/.vim/autoload` folder.

I want to use autocmd command to set the autoload event.

How should I do it.

Autoload the `SyntaxAttr.vim`.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#autoload-functions

Answer (score 1):

Assuming [this](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) is the `SyntaxAttr.vim` in question, the author of that script seems to be a little confused about the meaning of the word "autoloading" in the Vim context *and* about the purpose of the `autoload` directory (or "autoloading" didn't exist in its current form back in 2002).

For background, how so-called "autoloading" works in Vim is introduced in section 52 of the user manual, `:help 52.2` and further explained under `:help autoload`.

Now, you basically have two options:…

- Keep the file in `autoload/` but edit it and use it as described in the help sections above:

  ```
  " in autoload/SyntaxAttr.vim
  function! SyntaxAttr#SyntaxAttr()
  [...]

  " call that function manually
  :call SyntaxAttr#SyntaxAttr()

  " in your vimrc
  " use it in a custom command
  command! SA call SyntaxAttr#SyntaxAttr()

  " or in a mapping
  nnoremap <key> <Cmd>call SyntaxAttr#SyntaxAttr()<CR>
  ```
- Or move the file to where it belongs, `plugin/`, and forget all about that weird notion of "autoloading":

  ```
  " call that function manually
  :call SyntaxAttr()

  " in your vimrc
  " use it in a custom command
  command! SA call SyntaxAttr()

  " or in a mapping
  nnoremap <key> <Cmd>call SyntaxAttr()<CR>
  ```